# Is there a way to make content available when spring server is down?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, offline

I'm deploying my spring boot web application on a local server that could be down sometimes and I can't use server replication.
is there a way to cache the content of my application to make it available when the server is down?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [Load Balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) and create a copy of your server instance.
When a server is down, the traffic will be sent to the other.

AWS offers a very good solution for this: https://aws.amazon.com/es/elasticloadbalancing/?nc=sn&loc=0

Any solution would need another server. Even if you cache your information, another server is needed in order to get and serve your content.